# Error while using Elasticsearch with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement Elasticsearch in a Spring boot app, I followed the steps described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.finders) and everything works fine when it comes to client integration (using the recommended Hight Level Rest Client), mapping or indexing.. But when I try to query the documents I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-Je513EBi1vVkAiBdanX"
```

My config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
public class ElasticConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration configuration = ClientConfiguration.localhost();
        RestHighLevelClient client = RestClients.create(configuration).rest();
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(elasticsearchClient());
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findByName(String name);
}
```

My Service:

```
public List<User> getUsers(String qry){
    return userRepository.findByName(qry);
}
```

My Model:

```
@Document(indexName = "users")
public class User {

    @Id private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String avatar;
    private String bio;
    private boolean checked;

    public User() { }

    public User(
            @JsonProperty("id") Long id,
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("username") String username,
            @JsonProperty("avatar") String avatar,
            @JsonProperty("bio") String bio,
            @JsonProperty("checked") boolean checked) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.bio = bio;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    // Getters
    // Setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the version of Spring Data and Elasticsearch you are using? In addition, I'm a bit concerned on the way you implemented your RestHighLevelClient. You refer to a localhost but what about the port? 
Please find a snippet of working code below:

```
    @Bean
public RestHighLevelClient elasticRestClient () {
    String[] httpHosts = httpHostsProperty.split(";");
    HttpHost[] httpHostsAsArray = new HttpHost[httpHosts.length];
    int index = 0;

    for (String httpHostAsString : httpHosts) {
        HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(httpHostAsString.split(":")[0], new Integer(httpHostAsString.split(":")[1]), "http");
        httpHostsAsArray[index++] = httpHost;
    }

    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(httpHostsAsArray)
            .setRequestConfigCallback(builder -> builder
                    .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeOutInMs)
                    .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeOutInMs)
            );

    return new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
}
```

Comment: I tried this configuration but nothing changed. The implementation is working fine, the error only occurs if the query returns something. I'm using Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0